Bundle TS code with Webpack without compiling it to JS
I am using Webpack to bundle node.js app so I won't need to deploy node_modules to my serverless infrastructure.
Since Node.js 22 (LTS) officially supports Typescript, it now makes sense to only bundle node_modules dependencies with the TS app without compiling everything to the JS.
Theoretically, it should reduce build time.
Is it possible to achieve this with Webpack?

Ts is converted to js before webpack.  Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786199/using-webpack-to-generate-typescript-libraries-with-typing-files | https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter
